# When is $2^{2n}-2^n+1$ prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is it known when
$2^{2n}-2^n+1$
is prime?
It seems to be only when n is 1,2,4 or 32.

Comment: The short answer is no, we don't know whether there are infinitely many primes of this shape, and that this is well beyond what we can do.

Comment: Notice however that it is easily seen to be true that the only odd $n$ which gives a prime value is $n = 1$, since $2^{2n}-2^{n} + 1$ is divisible by $3$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Proth's Theorem is related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expanding on the remarks by Pace Nielsen (with an additional result that we need only consider $n>2$ a multiple of $4.$):

$x^n-1=\prod_{d \mid n}\phi_d(x)$. The factors are irreducible over the rationals.

In particular $$x^6-1=\phi_1(x)\phi_2(x)\phi_3(x)\phi_6(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

And $$\phi_6(x^n)=x^{2n}-x^n+1$$ is a factor of $x^{6n}-1.$ It is an irreducible rational polynomial exactly if  $n$ is of the form $n=2^i3^j,$ then $$\phi_6(x^n)=\phi_{6n}(x)$$ .

But if $p$ is prime to $6$ then $$\phi_6(u^p)=\phi_p(u)\phi_{6p}(u)$$ so for $n=pm$   $$\phi_{6}(x^n)=\phi_p(x^m)\phi_{6p}(x^m).$$

Accordingly, a necessary condition for  $b^{2n}-b^n+1$ to be prime is that $n$ is of the form $2^i3^j.$

In the event that $b \bmod 3=-1$ we also need $n$ even lest $b^{2n}-b^n+1 \bmod 3=0.$

Finally, in the given case that $b=2,$ we have that for $n=4k-2>2$ the integer $2^{2n}-2^n+1$ has two factors of roughly equal size.

For example $2^{36}-2^{18}+1=68719214593=246241\cdot 279073.$

This is due to the following interesting [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization)

$$\left(x^{4 k -2}+x^{2 k -1}+1+(x^{3 k -1}+x^{k})\right) \left(x^{4 k -2}+x^{2 k -1}+1-(x^{3 k -1}+x^{k})\right)\\ =x^{8 k -4}+(2 x^{6 k -3}-x^{6 k -2})-(x^{2 k}- 2 x^{2 k -1})+(3 x^{4 k -2}-2 x^{4 k -1})+1$$

Putting $x=2,$ the first two pairs become $0$ and the third $2^{4k-2}.$

So the question might be phrased "when does the Mersenne number $2^n-1$ have factors other than those suggested by algebra?" Here restricted to $n=6m.$ That is the subject of the [Cunningham Project](https://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/%7Essw/cun/) where much information (in very condensed form) can  be found.

Answer (score 6):

Based on standard heuristics, one should expect there to be infinitely many such $n$ (Edit: Actually see below). By the prime number theorem, the "chance" that $2^{2n}-2^n+1$ should be prime should be about $$\frac{1}{\log (2^{2n}-2^n+1) } \sim \frac{1}{n \log 2}.$$
Since $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log 2} $$ diverges we should expect infinitely many such primes, barring some congruence issue or factorization trick, which do not seem to show up.

We can however rule out some specific cases. For instance one can never have $5|n$ since $x^{10}-x^5 +1$ has  $(x^2-x+1)$ as a factor. This also rules out 7, 11, 13, 17, 19,23  as prime factors, but not 3. It is possible that $x^{2p} - x^p +1$ must always have a $x^2-x+1$ for any prime $p \geq 5$. Edit to note: This is true by Will Savin's remark below. And this means that one only can have n be a power of 2 times a power of 3, and if we redo the heuristic with that restriction we then expect only finitely many values.

Comment: Sure, $x^2-x+1$ divides $x^{2p}-x^p+1$ whenever $p$ is a prime $>3$, and in fact whenever $p$ is congruent to $\pm 1$ mod $6$, because $x^2-x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of a primitive $6$th root of unity and because the set of primitive $6$th roots of unity is preserved by the $p$th power map. This reduces to $n$ a power of $2$ times a power of $3$ which indeed flips the heuristic from infinite to finite.

Comment: @WillSawin Good point. Edited to note.

Comment: A similar argument, using the polynomial $x+1$, and considering primitive 2nd roots of unity, is how one limits the form of Fermat primes.

Comment: @PaceNielsen That's an interesting way of phrasing that argument. I've always thought of that as just arising from a factorization pattern from how how $x^k - 1$ for odd $k$. That does make where Will's approach is coming from slightly more clear.

Comment: Exactly.  One can view Will's argument in terms of the factorization of $x^{3k}-1$ into cyclotomic factors.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim.** If $2^{2n}-2^n+1$ is prime and $n>4$,  then $n=4m$ where

$$ m \equiv 0, 3, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 18, 21 \pmod {24} .$$
**Proof.**
By Aaron Meyerowitz's answer, we know $n=4m$ and $m>1$.

Noting $2^{24} \equiv 1 \pmod {241}$, $2^8-2^4+1=241$ and $2^{-8}-2^{-4}+1=\frac{241}{2^8}$, we have
$$2^{2\times4(6k\pm1)}-2^{4(6k\pm1)}+1 \equiv 2^{\pm8}-2^{\pm4}+1 \equiv 0\pmod {241} $$
then $m \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$.

Noting $2^{48} \equiv 1 \pmod {97}$, $2^{16}-2^8+1=97\cdot673$ and $2^{-16}-2^{-8}+1=\frac{97\cdot673}{2^{16}}$, we have
$$2^{2\times4(12k\pm2)}-2^{4(12k\pm2)}+1 \equiv 2^{\pm16}-2^{\pm8}+1 \equiv 0\pmod {97} $$
then $m \not\equiv \pm 2 \pmod {12}$.

Noting $2^{96} \equiv 1 \pmod {193}$, $2^{32}-2^{16}+1=193\cdot22253377$ and $2^{-32}-2^{-16}+1=\frac{193\cdot22253377}{2^{32}}$, we have
$$2^{2\times4(24k\pm4)}-2^{4(24k\pm4)}+1 \equiv 2^{\pm32}-2^{\pm16}+1 \equiv 0\pmod {193} $$
then $m \not\equiv \pm 4 \pmod {24}$.

Therefore
$$ m \equiv 0, 3, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 18, 21 \pmod {24} .$$

Moreover, we have the following conjecture

**Conjecture.**  $2^{2n}-2^n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {433}$ and $n=4m$ **iff**

$$\phi(m) = \phi(i + j) = \phi(i) + \phi(j) $$
and
$$\phi(m) = \phi(ik) = \phi(i)\phi(k)$$
for some $i, j, k$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

Numerical computation indicates that it is true for $1≤m≤500$.

```
m = 3, 15, 21, 33, 39, 51, 57, 69, 75, 87, 93, 105, 111, 123, 129, 141, 147, 159, 165, 177, 183, 195, 201, 213, 219, 231, 237, 249, 255, 267, 273, 285, 291, 303, 309, 321, 327, 339, 345, 357, 363, 375, 381, 393, 399, 411, 417, 429, 435, 447, 453, 465, 471, 483, 489.
```

See [A306771](http://oeis.org/A306771)  and [Question 405183](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405183) for  details.

**Question.** Why 433? And how to prove "iff"?